# Extracting first few letters from tokens

Tags: commerce, tokens

I am trying to generate Product SKU through Auto SKU which uses [tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token), but with tokens I get full names from fields such as store city, store name, product name, serial field.

```
[commerce-product:field-stores:field-city]
[commerce-product:field-stores]
[commerce-product:field-stores:id]
[commerce-product:type-name]
[commerce-product:field_serial]
```

But I only want to extract first 4 letters from city token and from store token. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Where you want to get the value? If in views you can use trim functionality.

Comment: Not in Views but in Product SKU , through auto sku module . which will display in products ./admin/commerce/products and also in  product display(content-type) through Product reference in field.